Can't Loop over JSON Array from JSON Property in WSO2 ESB
I'm trying to loop over static json array list and i store the json object into property and i want to log all values in this array
<inSequence>
    <property name="numbersJSONOBJ" scope="default" type="STRING" value="{&quot;numbers&quot;:[1,2,3]}"/>
    <property expression="json-eval($ctx:numbersJSONOBJ)" name="numbersList" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('numbersList')" name="numbers"/>
    </log>
    <foreach expression="$ctx:numbersList">
        <sequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="MSG" value="INSIDE FOR EACHE"/>
            </log>
            <log level="full">
                <property expression="json-eval($)" name="number"/>
            </log>
        </sequence>
    </foreach>
    <respond/>
</inSequence>

and the output logs is
[2024-06-28 15:12:42,719]  INFO {APIDeployer} - API named 'NumbersAPI' has been deployed from file : D:\Programs\WSO2\IntegrationStudio\runtime\microesb\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1719580362569TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car\NumbersAPI_1.0.0\NumbersAPI-1.0.0.xml [2024-06-28 15:12:42,719]  INFO {CappDeployer} - Successfully Deployed Carbon Application : SOAP_PostmanAPIs_To_RESTApisCompositeExporter_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT{super-tenant} [2024-06-28 15:12:45,778]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:NumbersAPI} numbers = {"numbers":[1,2,3]}

i'm expecting the values to be loged in the console but it does not happen

I tried an to use (Enrish Mediator to store a XML) or (Property to store the xml value as a "OM" type) and then use the ForEach Mediator with expression "$ctx:PropertyName//XMLListName and to see if it works fine add a Log Mediator with Full logging to log each message it iterate over it

You say that you "tried" this and gave it an accepted check mark.  So it worked?

Yes it works fine with XML instead of JSON

see this example here https://github.com/youssefGamalMohamed/wso2-ei-repo/blob/main/SOAP_PostmanAPIs_To_RESTApis/SOAP_PostmanAPIs_To_RESTApisConfigs/src/main/synapse-config/api/NumbersAPI.xml
